# PHP: strtotime not work from file_get_contents

Tags: javascript, php, html

Hello i try to convert date to strtotime but my code not work;

time.html - show current time like 2017-03-09 07:11:01

time.html

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getDateTime() {
        var now     = new Date(); 
        var year    = now.getFullYear();
        var month   = now.getMonth()+1; 
        var day     = now.getDate();
        var hour    = now.getHours();
        var minute  = now.getMinutes();
        var second  = now.getSeconds(); 
        if(month.toString().length == 1) {
            var month = '0' + month;
        }
        if(day.toString().length == 1) {
            var day = '0' + day;
        }   
        if(hour.toString().length == 1) {
            var hour = '0' + hour;
        }
        if(minute.toString().length == 1) {
            var minute = '0' + minute;
        }
        if(second.toString().length == 1) {
            var second = '0' + second;
        }   
        var dateTime = year + '-' + month + '-' + day + ' ' + hour + ':' + minute + ':' + second;   
        return dateTime;
    }

    document.write(getDateTime());
</script>
```

index.php

```
$file = file_get_contents("http://localhost/time.html");
$file = strtotime($file);
echo "Time: ". $file;
```

code work like this: strtotime("2017-03-09 07:11:01"); but i need with file_get_contents to get real time (current time), thanks in advance

Comment: Unfortunately `file_get_contents` does not have a JavaScript interpreter.

Comment: Any reason you're not using the [PHP time](http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php) functions? Why include JavaScript?

Comment: @JohnPavek php not show correct time i try and with timezone not work for me

Comment: Well this won't work either so maybe ask a question with the PHP code.

Answer (score 1):

javascript is client-side, so you cant get it from php, time.html will only print the date when a user reads it (will show the user time). If you want print the time in php you should use the php function `date()`, so you will get the server date (php is server-side), for example:

```
echo "Time: ". date("Y/m/d H:i:s");
```

Note: `strtotime()` is a function to check or convert a string to time format

Comment: not show correct time date(), i need just strtotime()